# Java LDAP Authentication using username and password

Tags: authentication, ldap, jndi

I have a working code snippet by which i can authenticate a user by `dn` and password. My requirement is that the user will be entering his username(`sAMAccountName`) and I want to authenticate using `sAMAccountName` and password. How can I modify this code to achieve it?

```
    String userName = "John P R-Asst General Manager";
    String passWord = "asdfgh123";
    String base ="OU=SOU,DC=example,DC=com";
    String dn = "cn=" + userName + "," + base;

    String ldapURL = "ldap://mdsdc3.example.com:389";
    authEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    authEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapURL);
    authEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    authEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, dn);
    authEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

    try {
        DirContext authContext = new InitialDirContext(authEnv);
        return true;

    } catch (NamingException namEx) {
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 45):

I hope this helps many of you.

You don't need to all user hierarchy with CN, DN, etc.

You can login just passing  domain\user  and password.

I've my code working as it is bellow:

```
try
    {
        // Set up the environment for creating the initial context
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://ldap_server:389");
        // 
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "domain\\user"); //we have 2 \\ because it's a escape char
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "test");

        // Create the initial context

        DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
        boolean result = ctx != null;

        if(ctx != null)
            ctx.close();

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {           
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I am having some many issues trying to get info from LDAP server, basically may because I am not familiar with those CD, CN, OU. What data should I ask for to be able to authenticate and get user data from LDAP? They already sent me the admin data and I could create the context with success, but later on I need to get user info based on the "username", can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to complete `Context.PROVIDER_URL` like this :

```
String ldapURL = "ldap://mdsdc3.example.com:389/DC=example,DC=com";
```

I Think it would be better to use GSSAPI, perhaps you can have a look [here](http://jeftek.com/222/using-java-code-with-active-directory/) and [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/ldap.html)