# Get group name of LDAP authenticated user

Tags: java, authentication, ldap

I am using LDAP authentication using this class InitialDirContext , how can I get the group of the user which I have authenticated from the returned Object of this class InitialDirContext , 
I am using LDAP authentication like below link

[Java LDAP Authentication using username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302870/java-ldap-authentication-using-username-and-password)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

InitialDirContext Object won't give you any of those information on a platter.

First you will have to search for the groups under an OU (Organizational Unit) of interest.

InitialDirContext.search("",filter) [Filter = (objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames)]

It will give you a NamingEnumration of SearchResults (groups). 
Iterate through the SerachResults and get the Attributes associated with each groups.
Iterate through the Attributes for 'uniqueMember' attribute, value of which will be a member of the group (user/group). 
Check if it matches you user name.

Comment: Oh come on. You shoudl add `(uniqueMember={0})` to the filter, and provide the user's DN as a filter argument. Then you will only get the groups of which he is a member. No explicit attribute searching required at all.

Comment: Thanks EJP & Roshith .. @EJP can you give me sample code of how to get the group attribute for specific user

Comment: @EJP well I was trying to answer in the simplest possible way as the questioner seemed to be beginner to LDAP/JNDI stuff. Don't think that deserves a down vote!